# Divide a $1 by 3 and adjusting 1 cent

Tags: php

I have a price stored in a shopping cart table and trying to find a way to adjust 1 cent when price is divided by 3 or any other odd numbers.

```
$cost = '1';
$split  = '3';

$check1 = $cost/$split; // .33
$check2 = $cost/$split; // .33
$check3 = $cost/$split; // this should give .34
```

How can I adjust the difference?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) My first though is just doing `$check3 = $cost - $check1 - $check2;`

Comment: You're setting the split as a variable which suggests that it's going to change. On that basis why are you creating variables such as `$check1`, `$check2`, etc. If split was 4 then there is no fourth check var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$cost = 1;
$split = 3;
$check1 = $cost/split;
$total = intval($check1*100)*($split-1);
$diff = $cost - $total/100;
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if you want to have unlimited `$checks` and only have the last `$check` include the remainder, you could do something like:

```
<?php
    $cost=1;
    $split=3;
    $q=round($cost/$split,2);
    $r=$cost-($split*$q);

    $firstchecks=$q;
    $lastcheck=$q+$r;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not rounding up to second decimal:

```
function roundUp ($v,$d = 2 ) { 
     $p=pow(10,$d); 
     $c=ceil($p*$v);
     return ($c+ceil($p*$v-$c))/$p; 
} 

echo roundUp(1/3); // 0.34
```